# How do you overwrite or delete auto keying?

Tags: animation, keyframes

When I use autokey frames, I can only record an objects movement once and then I'm stuck with it. It doesn't matter what variant of menu choices I select from the auto keyframe dropdown box, nothing will overwrite the keyframes with a new set.

I have to go to collection and individually delete "animation' from each object. Which is especially frustrating when I've animated a series of objects at the same time.

[image]

Comment: You can delete them from Timeline in a single click (or Dope Sheet, Graph Editor, ...).

Comment: How? The timeline shows a blue line and nothing else for multiple objects. No keyframes.

Comment: You probably scrolled timeline down ... scroll up or go to View > Frame All